# Which multi-objective optimization algorithm should one select?

Tags: optimization, multi-objective-optimization, genetic-algorithm

The multi-objective optimization problem in my case is defined below:

- Objective 1: Minimize $f_1(X_1,X_2)=C_1X_1+C_2X_2+C_3X_1^2+C_4X_2^2+C_5X_1^2X_2^2$
- Objective 2: Minimize $f_2(X_1,X_2)=D_1X_1+D_2X_2+D_3X_1^2+D_4X_2^2+D_5X_1^2X_2^2$
- Objective 3: Minimize $f_3(X_2)=-E_1X_2$
- Constraint 1: $ 0 \le X_1 \le A_1$
- Constraint 2: $ 0 \le X_2 \le A_2$
- Constraint 3: $ X_1 + X_2 \le A_3$

Here, $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4,C_5,D_1,D_2,D_3,D_4,D_5,E_1,A_1,A_2$ and $A_3$ are positive constant numbers. $X_1$ and $X_2$ are decision variables.

I have used a real-coding method for chromosome coding and used NSGA-II for optimization. I used NSGA-II since it is the most commonly adopted method for arriving at a Pareto front. However, to use NSGA-II, is it always required to prove the NP-Hardness of a problem?

To calculate the computational complexity of a NSGA-II problem, we need to calculate both the complexity for each generation and the number of generations<sup>[[1]](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82006684.pdf)</sup>.

Let's say that the complexity is $\mathcal O(G\cdot F\cdot P^2)=\mathcal O(100\cdot3\cdot100^2)$. Here, $G$ is number of generations, $F$ is the number of objective functions, and $P$ is the population size.

How do we justify the use of NSGA-II in this case?

---

<sub>Reference</sub>

<sub>[1] Curry, D. M., Dagli, C. H. (2014). Computational Complexity Measures for Many-objective Optimization Problems. *Procedia Computer Science.* 36:185-191.</sub>

Comment: Are the objectives all convex functions?

Comment: If i did the math correctly, the determinant of the hessian of objective 2 is $4a^{2}u^{2}v^{2} + 4acv^{2} + 4abu^{2} + 4bc - 16a^{2}u^{2}v^{2}$ where $a = D_5$, $b=D_3$, $c = D_4$, $u = X_{1}$, $v = X_{2}$. The objective function is convex at the points $(u, v)$ if this determinant is positive and $2av^{2} + 2b > 0$ ... If the objective is convex within your other constraints, then it is good news. Unlikely, but I don't know the values of your constants. The feasible region is convex because it is the intersection between a rectangle and the area under a line.

Comment: I agree with Michael's comment at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187024/which-multi-objective-optimization-algorithm-should-one-select too. The objectives are smooth and simple. I think evolution algorithm looks like an overkill.

Comment: Cross-posted widely: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4187024/14578, https://or.stackexchange.com/q/6518/2415, https://mathoverflow.net/q/396528/37212, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/49192/5038.   Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  You have asked two different questions in the body of your post, and a third one in the title.  Please pick one question to ask; if you want to ask multiple questions, ask them in separate posts.  Please define exactly what you mean by solving this multi-objective problem: do you want to enumerate all solutions on the Pareto front?  to find one Pareto-optimal solution?  to find a solution that trades off all of the objective functions somehow (and if so, how do you want to manage and formalize that tradeoff)?

Comment: Since duplicates get deleted, here is my comment at the other site: Can the $\epsilon$-constraint method work? The weighted sum method seems to require convex objective space. https://engineering.purdue.edu/~sudhoff/ee630/Lecture09.pdf

Comment: @QuriousCube Thanks a lot for your comments. I agree with you and I think e-constraint method is most appropriate. I am trying to solve the problem using it.